# How can I convert a List to another List via map method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have blow code in `flutter`. The type of `_transactions` is `List<TransactionModel>`.  But I got an error `Error: Expected a value of type 'List<TransactionModel>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'`. How can I convert the `dynamic` to `TransactionModel` in the list?

```dart
class TransactionModel {
  final String id;

  TransactionModel({this.id});

  factory TransactionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TransactionModel(id: json['id']);
  }
}

var transactions = result.data['getTransactions']['transactions'];
_transactions = transactions.map((e) => TransactionModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: do you use a firebase? have a look 
 at this snippet.[link]https://dartpad.dartlang.org/79dafa97be260b86a84bbb852ab367fe?null_safety=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
_transactions = List<TransactionModel>.from(transactions.map((e) => TransactionModel.fromJson(e)).toList());
```

Comment: it works, but why do I need to add `List<TransactionModel>.from` in the front?

Comment: It's basically another form of `casting`. Where you tell flutter to treat the item in the dynamic list, as a TransacationModel elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
_transactions = transactions.map((e) => TransactionModel.fromJson(e)).toList() as List<TransactionModel>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @Mahdi, it would be great if you could add a bit more of explanation!